# Trying to add custom scrollbar to my site (webkit// brower specific css isn't an option)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

I am trying to add custom scroll bar to several divs on my site, using webkit or browser specific css files aint an option right now.

I am left with JS solutions. So far I've tried 2 plugins and both seemed to have problems and throw an error to firebug.

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

The above plugins both throw an error for jquery 1.8.2 and 1.8.3.

is there any other plugin that works on those jquery versions ?

Comment: Check what is the maximum version of jQuery this plugin supports. Starting with 1.8, there are major changes in jQuery and do not always provide backward compatibility. The plugin may properly function with a lower jQuery version.

Comment: I used "jScrollPane" with 1.8 and had to modify it a bit because of the behaviour of the jQuery "attr" method. I could give you the revision I've done.

Comment: Marcell thanks. floobar thanks as well i just going to use 1.4.2 for that part of the site i guess for now. might write a little plugin using jquery ui sliders for that my self later on.